# Uploading Images to Azure(easy Tables)

Tags: sql, sqlite, azure, local-storage, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure App Service (Mobile Apps) and would like to upload images via the mobile app. I would prefer to load it into a table with column of data type varbinary(max), which I can use to store images. However, in Easy Tables (in the Azure Portal), I only see data type options String, Number, Date and Boolean. 
Please cann any one show me a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Table Storage **is not** a relational database and only supports a subset of value data types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#property-types

So you need to either...

1. Store images in a [Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) and the URLs in Easy Tables/Table Storage
2. Store the images in the included "MySQL In App" database. But I wouldn't use this one since there are some [limitations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/18/announcing-mysql-in-app-preview-for-web-apps/).
3. Use the Azure SQL Database to store the images or just the URLs (and use again Azure blob storage to store the images)

I would suggest 1 or 3 with storing the images in a blob storage. Storing images in a database is not such a good idea since a) you have a higher load on your database and b) you might have a hard to using browser caching or a CDN.

Comment: i think option one looks very good, do u have any article that shows how it implemented. I am also thinking of converting the image to a base 64 string then store in easy table then retrieve the string and convert back to BitMap Image anytime i want to display the image.

Comment: There is a description for the most popular services available on how to interact with blob storage. Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) to the .NET desc. Also I think the storage of base64 converted images won't work since there is a 64KB limit for table storage entries as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you so very much, u been of tremendous help.